# Child style applying to parent component in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular

I'm using Bootstrap css as a global style, and then modify it in each component if I need to, in `index.htm` I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and then in the child I add the style

```
.nav li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

which also overrides the value the parent receives from bootstrap for nav li a, is this considered ok? Maybe I don't really understand the Shadow DOM...

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/O2r3zKlYj7SH7FWHvWnT?p=preview

(But you have to launch it on you pc, because I'm not sure how to make "@import '/styles/UIComponent.css';" in customer.component.css work in plunker, this way it imports the css file in header and makes it global. If you change the line to "@import '../styles/UIComponent.css';" (the two dots added) it won't import the whole css, and the emulator will translate it as needed.)

**Edit**: 
It's a bug in current Angular2 beta: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6449

Comment: Do you use the default `ViewEncapsulation` (`Emulated`) or `None` or `Native`?

Comment: @Silencer css styles will be applied based on html structure. please add the html for parent and child which have the same class name

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the default one, Emulated, I'm not modifying it.

Comment: @Silencer to avoid child styles being applied to parent, you need have the selector like `.parent-class-name [for more specific].nav li a {`

Comment: @Venugopal So you're saying that it is normal for child styles to affect the parent ? That was actually the question. While at the same time, styles defined in a parent doesn't affect the child, kind of strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
:host .nav li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

This way you are limiting the scope of your styles to your child component.
With `ViewEncapsulation.None` this doesn't work of course because this is about style encapsulation and `None` disables exactly this.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I find it strange that parent styles don't affect the child, while the child styles does affect the parent...

Comment: I would need to see more of your HTML and CSS to tell. Just investigate the styles and the DOM in your browsers devtools. The selectors are rewritten for style encapsulation by polyfills. I can't reproduce your problem with my simple example. `:host` limits to the shadow DOM of the current element. This selector is easy to rewrite. Maybe you run into an edge case where this didn't work. It might be a bug.

Comment: I think I found the bug: inside another child css: customer.component.css I imported the other css: "@import '/styles/UIComponents.css';" , I think it was a stupid think to do, as it seems that it somehow screwed up the emulation and inserted the UIComponent.css into the document, afecting all elements.

Comment: does this mean it's a bug in Angular2, the parent doesn't even inherit the style from <style> like the other components, but somehow directly from the file "UIComponents.css". Sorry for all the questions, as you can see I'm not an expert in the field :)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't even inherit the style from `<style>`" - style in head, style in component, which one, .... "but somehow directly from the file "UIComponents.css" - where do you reference/import this file? It's really hard to imagine what's going on on your site. Could you create a Plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: I rebuilt the example locally in Dart but I can't reproduce. (I don't use TS and don't even know how)

Comment: ViewEncapsulation emulate with root "/" import :@import("/styles/UIComponent.css") gets emulated into: <style> @import '/styles/UIComponents.css'; </style> making this file global in my understanding. Maybe ask about this on angular issue page ? It was also strange to me, that the same styles were repeated a lot of times while inspecting with chrome dev tools, it seems the reason was this, having multiple imports of the same css, made the same file being included globally a lot of times.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how imports in TS work. This is where TS and Dart differ quite a lot (while the code is quite similar). You might try another question more specific to this import issue. A working Plunker would be great, or just link the same Plunker in the new question and try to get help to make it work.

Comment: Well I cannot access root paths in plunker from CSS... And this is the CSS import inside the CSS file, not the import directive  from angular. Thanks for all you help, you helped me a lot understand all this stuff better. Maybe I will ask the question on angular issue page, I've seen you are also active there. And anyway as i understand in CSS should be used only relative paths, not the way I did, using the root path :)